# Retrieve token value from the request within web api action

Tags: c#, .net, rest, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity

I have a web api controller in which I used a token bearer to authenticate connected user :

```
protected ApplicationUserManager UserManager
{
    get
    {

        return _UserManager ?? HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    }
}

[Route("Create")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult CreateEvent(CreateEventModel model)
{
     String userID = UserManager.FindByName(User.Identity.Name).Id;
    int EventID = EventRep.CreateEvent(userID, model.EventTitle, model.EventDate, model.NbParticipent, model.Description, model.Logo);
    if(EventID > 0) return Ok(EventID);
    return BadRequest("paramètres invalides") ;
}
```

Because a restful application must be stateless, I'd like to avoid using `User.Identity` and replace this line

```
String userID = UserManager.FindByName(User.Identity.Name).Id;
```

I need to retrieve the token bearer from the request and then find the 
corresponding user.

So :

1. How can I do this?
2. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Create a DelegateHandler or ActionFilter and inspect the header for bearer token. You can then retrieve the user, create a proper Principal of the user and set it in the thread and httpcontext

Comment: @Nkosi please post your comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `DelegateHandler` or `ActionFilter` to inspect the request headers for bearer token.

You can then retrieve the user, create a proper `IPrincipal` of the user and set it in the current thread and `HttpContext`.